# How can I keep watching my tasks on gulp 4?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I noticed that I couldn't run gulp watch on my site because of the node version I have(12) and gulp 4.
So I just upgraded to gulp 4 and reinstalled all the npm packages following the npm audit instructions. My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('imagemin', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/images'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
gulp.src('./src/lib/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./src/lib/*.js', gulp.parallel('uglify'));
    gulp.watch(['./src/css/style.css', 
        './src/**/*.twig', 
        './src/js/*.js'], function (files){
        livereload.changed(files)
    });
});
```

When I run gulp watch command,  it says "Starting watch", but nothing is being watched when I look at the in the browser and files.

How can I keep watching my tasks on gulp 4?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing is being watched"?  Files will be watched to see if they are changed after starting the `watch` task does not trigger until there has been a change unless you use the `ignoreInitial` option - so that the watched files will trigger their tasks on first-run.

Answer (score 0):

Add **return** statement inside your 'sass' and 'uglify' task to notify when task finished like this:

```
gulp.task('uglify', function() {
return gulp.src('./src/lib/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js'))
});
```

Comment: Does work. When I run gulp watch, the console says that the watch started, but when I change anything in the sass file nothing gets compiled

Comment: try also in last gulp.watch add task instead of function like this gulp.watch(['./src/css/style.css', 
        './src/**/*.twig', 
        './src/js/*.js'], gulp.series('liveReload')); and then trigger changed inside new task liveReload